# How do include read-only formatted multi-line text in a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a splash screen with multi-line text with minimal formatting (font size, font color, superscript, unerline).
How do I create a dialog with this multi-line text with formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Windows form that is and open it modally.  If you need to know what the user clicked you can have it return a DialogResult value.  You can display multiple line of text using either a Textbox and set the Readonly property to true or using a Label control.  Both a Textbox and a Label have a Multiline property that you can set to true to allow multiple lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

How is the text formatted?  HTML?  RTF?  Or is that up to you?

Is the text static, or dynamic?

For no formatting, use a single label or multiple label controls.  You can also use multiple label controls if you have completely separate labels that need different formatting.

For no formatting with a large amount of text that may wrap off the screen, use a read-only multi-line text box with a scrollbar.

For rich text, use a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996492.aspx).

For HTML, drop in a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxc145fz.aspx) control.

Comment: Formatting is up to me.  Text is static.

Comment: Then I agree with Henk and R. Bemrose, use a `RichTextBox` and load it with some rich text.  Make it read-only and multi-line.

Answer (score 0):

If you need formatted text, use a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) Control, with both `ReadOnly = true;` and `Multiline = true;`

Note that it's probably easier to make an RTF file that looks like you want it, then use RichTextBox's [`RichTextBbx1.LoadFile("path\to\file");`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f99sst7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)